# How can I buy 'Mastering Monero' via XMR?

Tags: how-to, payment

***'Mastering Monero: The future of private transactions'*** is now available on Amazon. How can I buy it paying with XMR?

Comment: If you're going to use bitrefill, you should convert xmr to Dash instead of btc. Dash has instantSend. You can use a shapeshift alt or use an exchange since dash has privacy too. But Dash works better with bitrefill

Comment: You should use 'comment' to give this kind of info. Also, you must use an exchange to convert xmr to dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until an option to buy it directly through Monero will be available (you can check it on https://masteringmonero.com/), you can buy ***'Mastering Monero: The future of private transactions'*** with **XMR** in this way:

1. use https://xmr.to/ to convert Monero in Bitcoin
2. use converted coins to buy a gift card for Amazon at https://www.bitrefill.com/ or with another similar service
3. use that gift card to buy 'Mastering Monero' on Amazon at [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1731079966/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1731079966)